# Trying to prove infinite primes by infinite coprime sequences.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Rules**

Infinite primes do not exist.

**Conjecture**

There exists infinite coprime sequences of the form

$a_n = \{(k, n-k) \,\  |\  \, 1 \le k < n,\  \gcd(k, n-k) = 1\}$

proving infinite primes exist.

**Examples**

$a_2\ =\{(1,1)\}$
$a_3\ =\{(1, 2), (2, 1)\}$
$a_5\ =\{(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)\}$
$a_7\ =\{(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 3), (5, 2), (6, 1)\}$
$a_{11}=\{(1,10), (2,9), (3,8), (4,7), (5,6), (6,5), (7,4), (8,3), (9,2), (10,1)\}$
...
$a_n\  =\small \{(1,n-1),...,(\left \lfloor{\frac{n}2-2}\right \rfloor ,\left \lceil{\frac{n}2+2}\right \rceil),,(\left \lfloor{\frac{n}2}\right \rfloor ,\left \lceil{\frac{n}2}\right \rceil),(\left \lceil{\frac{n}2}\right \rceil ,\left \lfloor{\frac{n}2}\right \rfloor),,(\left \lceil{\frac{n}2+2}\right \rceil ,\left \lfloor{\frac{n}2-2}\right \rfloor),...,(n-1,1)\}$

**Notes**

The $n^{th}$ sequence always has several known coprimes as shown.

Comment: My gut instinct is that this is a *consequence* of the infinitude of primes, rather than a fruitful proof approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a sequence $a_n$ satisfies your requirements, then we have:
$$\gcd(k,n-k)=1$$
for all $1 \leqslant k <n$. By the Euclidean Algorithm, this means $\gcd(k,n)=1$ for all $1 \leqslant k < n$. Since $n>1$, and since $\gcd(k,n)=1$ for all $k<n$, this is equivalent to saying that $n$ is prime. Clearly, our requirement holds when $n$ is prime. Moreover, $n$ cannot be composite, since if $k$ is a divisor of $n$ that is neither $1$ or $n$, then $\gcd(k,n)=k \neq 1$. Hence, $a_n$ satisfies your requirements iff $n$ is prime. Hence:
$$\text{infinite $a_n$ $\iff$ infinite primes }$$

Comment: Trying to prove infinite $a_n \implies$ infinite primes, not infinite primes $\implies$ infinite $a_n$. Thanks.

Comment: @vengy The required edits have been made

Comment: You seem to have shown only that whenever a sequence is formed by coprime naturals then you have a prime. There is no proof that there exist infinite number of these sequences. – DonAntonio